# Nested where in sequelize includes

Tags: sequelize.js

I trying to read the current value of the fieldA from table modelA, to filter in where at modelC.
is it possible by this way?
I try: **db.modelA.fieldA**, or ['modelA','fieldA'], or ['fieldA], without success.

```
await db.modelA.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.modelB,
      attributes: ["fieldB"],
      include: [
        {
          model: db.modelC,
          where: { fieldC: { $lte: **db.modelA.fieldA** } },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Not sure whether this will work, but try `$lte: sequelize.col('modelA.fieldA'), ` or  `$lte: sequelize.col('fieldA'), `

Comment: it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved]

```
await db.modelA.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.modelB,
      attributes: ["fieldB"],
      include: [
        {
          model: db.modelC,
          on: {
            fieldC: {
              $lte: { $col: "modelA.fieldA" },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```